# How can I run Rust code on a STM32F415 target?

Tags: rust, embedded, cross-compiling

I am trying to get the [Blinky](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal/blob/master/examples/delay-syst-blinky.rs) example from the [STM32F4xx HAL crate](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal) to run on a STM32F415RGT6 target. I have modified the example code, so that an led connected to pin PC13 will blink instead of the default (Doesn't exist on my board). I can get the code to compile just fine and I can upload the hex file to the board, however, it looks as if the code doesn't run, and I see no change in the LED.

My Cargo.toml looks as follows:

```
[package]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
embedded-hal = "0.2"
nb = "1"
cortex-m = "0.7"
cortex-m-rt = "0.7"
# Panic behaviour, see https://crates.io/keywords/panic-impl for alternatives
panic-halt = "0.2"

[dependencies.stm32f4xx-hal]
version = "0.15.0"
features = ["stm32f415"] # replace the model of your microcontroller here
# and add other required features
```

With my .cargo/config being the same as the one they have in the [example](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal/blob/master/.cargo/config).

Finally I have edited the memory.x file to match the spec of the target:

```
MEMORY
{
  /* NOTE K = KiBi = 1024 bytes */
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
}

/* This is where the call stack will be allocated. */
/* The stack is of the full descending type. */
/* NOTE Do NOT modify `_stack_start` unless you know what you are doing */
_stack_start = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
```

To get the code onto the target, I first compile it with cargo, and then run

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/hello hello.hex
```

to convert the output to a hex file that can then be flashed to the chip.

As mentioned, I have no success in getting the code to run successfully on the target. Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a closer look at the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f415rg.html), I changed the memory.x file to:

```
MEMORY
{
  /* NOTE K = KiBi = 1024 bytes */
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

/* This is where the call stack will be allocated. */
/* The stack is of the full descending type. */
/* NOTE Do NOT modify `_stack_start` unless you know what you are doing */
_stack_start = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
```

And got the example code to run.